# How to add input to command line prompt from wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, command-line-interface

So I have this code on python, that retrieves output from console when executing shell commands.

```
def OnClick(self, event):
    cmd = self.command.GetValue()
    if cmd:
        input, output, errors = os.popen3(cmd)
        errors = errors.read()
    if errors:
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, errors,
        'An error occurred',
        wx.OK | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        self.output.SetValue('')
    else:
        self.output.SetValue(output.read())
```

This works well in simple prints, but I have a password prompt on console, that I'd like to interact from wxPython. Is it possible and how would you do it in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you have a long running process, you need to use a thread. See wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks for several example solutions. When you get to the password prompt, you can send some kind of notification to the GUI to display a dialog using wx.CallAfter or wx.PostEvent. There are ways to communicate with a thread, but I'll leave you to Google for that as it's beyond the scope of a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks, its give some ideas. I found this is very near what I mean, but not exactly: http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter

I'd like to keep console out from view and interact only from wxPython. Need to research more tomorrow...

Comment: I would recommend posting to the wxPython mailing list. They can give you more pointed advice.